# Can I install node.js 18 on Centos 7 and do I need python 3 install too?

Tags: python, node.js, linux, centos

I'm not sure if node.js 18 supports centos 7 and is it a requirement to install python 3 for node.js 18?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Step 1 - `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo bash -`

Step 2 - `sudo yum -y install nodejs`

I don't think you need Python 3.

Reference - https://computingforgeeks.com/install-node-js-on-centos-rhel-rocky-linux/

Comment: This is incorrect. The reference instructions are for CentOS 8. The most recent answer from 8th of August 2022 is correct, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 18):

Starting v18, Node.js no longer supports centos 7 and a few other Linux distros due to glibc version incompatibility. See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43246.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can,
but you have to solve related issues ( upgrade make,gcc,glibc,python versions etc)

Answer (score 0):

No, Node18 requires CentOS 8 or higher. Even if you directly install it locally, it will not take effect. There are issues with drivers such as gcc glic, so don't waste time trying, either give up Node18 or upgrade the system.

Comment: This cannot be considered to be an answer but you can add this in as a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35141701)

Answer (score 0):

2024 update: it appears that this is possible using [github.com/nodejs/unofficial-builds](https://github.com/nodejs/unofficial-builds/) ([source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43246#issuecomment-1845312339)). On the target system check the glibc version:

```bash
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

And then pull the needed archive from [unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release](https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release) (e.g. `node-v18.18.2-linux-x64-glibc-217.tar.gz`).

I can't vouch for this method since this is the point I surrender and stick with the node16 release in RHEL7 epel.

Answer (score -2):

I am sure you can install NodeJS 18 on Centos7.

Regarding of the Python need.
Yes you will need python installed, NodeJS use some python code. Python is required for building node from source

Comment: I am not so sure. And the reason is that when I try it using the method in the accepted answer, I get missing dependencies for GLIBCXX_3.4.21, GLIBC_2.28, and CXXABI_1.3.9.